# Can k (proportionate growth rate) be interpreted as $e^k-1$ (the proportion added/removed each period)?

Tags: exponential-function, population-dynamics

I am confused between:

- k: the proportionate growth rate

and

- $e^k-1$: the proportion added/removed each unit period

For example, if I have a population following the exponential growth function:

$P = P_0e^{0.04t}$ (so $k= 0.04$ year$^{-1}$)

and I am asked the proportion of the population which is added each year it's:

$\frac{P-P_0}{P_0}= e^k-1$

In numbers:

$e^{0.04}-1= 0.040810...$

So it's very close to $k$ but not quite. I would interpret this as "the population is growing by 4.08% each year".

This confused me because it's exactly what I thought the factor $k$ was meaning: the growth rate of a population. And indeed, in number they are very close ($k= 0.04$ and $e^k-1= 0.040810...$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write $e^{0.04^t}$ as $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{0.04}{n}\right)^{n\cdot t}$. This is a continuous growth.

For $t=1$ (one year) we have $e^{0.04}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{0.04}{n}\right)^{n}$. Here we have $n$ growths per year with an growth rate of $\frac{0.04}{n}$, where $n$ goes to infinity.

Now we can look what the growth rate is when the number of growth intervals do not go to infinity, but it can be  large: $\left(1+\frac{0.04}{n}\right)^{n}$

We can use the binomial theorem to obtain $\left(1+\frac{0.04}{n}\right)^{n}=\color{blue}{1+0.04}+\binom{n}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{0.04}2\right)^2+...$

We see for every $n>1$ it is greater than $1.04$ and only for $n=1$ we have an equality :$\left(1+\frac{0.04}{1}\right)^{1}=1.04$.

Conclusion: We can divide our growth period into $n$ growth sub-intervals with an growth rate $\frac{r}n$. But then the growth rate of the overall period is greater than $r$. In the case of $n\to \infty$ the growth rate of the overall period becomes $e^r-1>r$.

Comment: So e^r-1 and r both represent growth rate, but e^r-1 is just a more precise calculation (like dividing the period into an infinity of sub-intervals)?

Comment: No, it depends on the context which model you use. When it is reasonable you can model the population growth as a continuous process and use $P(t)=P_0\cdot e^{0.04t}$ Or you say you want a model with a yearly growth rate of $r$ then you use $P(t)=(1+r)^t$, Basically they are not very different. You can transform $(1+r)^t$ into $e^{\large{\ln(1+r)\cdot t}}$. Both expressions are equal. // In financial context the sub intervals can make a difference, if you make  payments during the sub-intervals.